# Soup find all not returing any values

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the current online members from [this website](https://redeyecheats.com/).
Ive looked all over google and I cannot find a solution to my problem. I am trying to grab the information like so:

```
soup.find('div', {"ol": "listInline"})
```

but this is returning Nothing.
This is the html:`<ol class="listInline"></ol>`
Inside that html is a list of all the online users. How would I fix this

Comment: Look into your soup variable. Is the div there? (these sites usually generate content using javascript after the site is loaded).

Comment: Its there, its just nested in like 20 divs

Comment: There is no `listInline` in the page source anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`soup.select('div ol[class="listInline"]')` will get the result you want

Comment: This still gives me no response, try it with the linked website and see if you can get A result

Comment: @shtabbbe I can't find this element `<ol class="listInline"></ol>` in your website, can you show me your html.

Comment: when the content gets printed, it prints only the highest parent and no the divs in the parent div, is that problem?

Comment: no , I mean that I can't find `<ol class="listInline"></ol>` in your website through search directly.